# Assign Template Driven Variable To Reactive Form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

How can i assign the this.product.amount from the ngOnInit() to my reactive form variable called available_amount? Is there a way to do it? Thank you.

```
this.productForm = this.fb.group({
            available_amount: [null, Validators.required]
        })


ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.route.params
        .subscribe((params: Params) => {
            this.id = +params['id'];
            this.ProductsService.getProduct(this.id)
            .subscribe(
                (data:any) => {
                    this.product = data.product[0];
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    alert("ERROR");
                })
        }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a function to create the form

```
createForm(data:any)
{
  this.productForm = this.fb.group({
      <!--if pass data to argument, the value of available_amout was
          data.amount, else null -->
          available_amount: [data?data.amount:null, Validators.required]
  })
}
```

Then, use this function in ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.route.params
        .subscribe((params: Params) => {
            this.id = +params['id'];
            this.ProductsService.getProduct(this.id)
            .subscribe(
                (data:any) => {
                    this.product = data.product[0];
                    createForm(this.product) //<--call the function
                },
                error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    alert("ERROR");
                })
        }); 
}
```

NOTE: I supouse your this.product has a property called "amount" change according your real code

Comment: Is it not possible to do like this? this.productForm.[available_amount] = this.product.amount.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I think that is: this.producForm.controls['available_amount'].setValue(this.product.amount)